# Run All the Tests

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, code-coverage, testng, emma

Is there a way to run all the tests in multiple eclipse projects?

I have a maven multi module project and want to use emma to show me code, that is not covered by any tests, not matter in which submodule it lies. So my idea is to have a single emma-coverage run, that includes all the tests of all my modules.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) which runs your tests in an ant/emma context and generates a report - the report component is able to merge the results from each submodule into a single report.